# When is the Taylor series bounded by a partial sum?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

**Cliff notes**: Is there a nice, general property of a Taylor series that shows when it is everywhere bounded by its partial sum. E.g., is there a nice/simple way to show that
$$
\cos(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-4\pi^2 x^2)^i}{(2i)!} \geq \sum_{i=0}^{2k+1}\frac{(-4\pi^2 x^2)^i}{(2i)!} \qquad (*)
$$
for all integers $k \geq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, or say, that
$$
\cos(x)\cos(x^2) = 1-x^2/2 - 11x^4/24 + \cdots \geq 1-x^2/2 - 11x^4/24 \qquad (**) \; .
$$

---

It is often extremely useful not just to *approximate* a Taylor series by its partial sum, but to *bound* it. E.g., we very frequently use the inequality

$$e^{-x} = 1 - x + x^2/2 - x^3/6 + x^4/24 - \cdots \geq 1-x 
\; .$$

(I'm using $e^{-x}$ instead of just $e^x$ to stress the fact that the summands can be negative, since the inequality is completely trivial otherwise.)

We typically prove this from the convexity of $e^{-x}$, which immediately implies that
$$
x^2/2 - x^3/6 + x^4/24 - \cdots
$$
is non-negative. But, for even slightly more complicated cases, like the inequality
$$
\cos(x) = 1- x^2/2 + x^4/24 - \cdots \geq 1-x^2/2 \qquad (***)
\; ,
$$
this simple technique fails.

In fact, the best proof of $(***)$ that I know observes that the inequality is trivial except in a small interval around zero, in which the fourth derivative of $\cos(x)$ (which is just $\cos(x)$) is positive. My main gripe with this proof is that it gets quite ugly when we try to generalize it. Proving $(*)$ with this strategy is already a pain, and generalizing to even slightly less pretty functions like that in $(**)$ seems like a nightmare.

Is there a nice way to handle such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the original question that I asked was far too general and vague, but with Siyao Guo and Alex Lombardi we at least found a cute proof that, e.g.,

$$1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6} + \cdots - \frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!} \leq e^{-x} \leq 1-x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots + \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}
\; $$

for integer $k \geq 1$ and $x \geq 0$. We can similarly prove bounds for $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. I doubt this is original, but since I couldn't find it by Googling, I figured it was worth posting.

Equivalently, we want to prove that the tail of the series satisfies
$$f_k(x) := \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i \frac{x^{k+i}}{(k+i)!} \geq 0
\; $$
for $x \geq 0$.
The proof is by induction on $k$. The base case is $k = 0$, which is trivial since $f_k(x) = e^{-x}$. For $k \geq 1$, we simply note that the derivative satisfies $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x} f_k(x) = f_{k-1}(x)$. By induction, the derivative is positive for $x \geq 0$, and the result follows from the fact that $f_k(0) = 0$.

The proof for $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ is essentially the same and works by just replacing $f_k$ by

$$g_k(x) := \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{x^{k + 2i}}{(k+2i)!}
\; ,$$

so that $g_0(x) = \cos(x)$, $g_1(x) = \sin(x)$, and $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x} g_k(x) = g_{k-1}(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a nice way to handle such things?

Not for all sums. But for sums coming from objects like sine and cosine expansions, you can use the bound coming from alternating series. More formally, if you are interested in
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n a(n)$$
and the $a(n)$ satisfy

1. $a(n) \geq 0$
2. $a(n) \geq a(n+1)$
3. $a(n) \to 0$

then you have that

$$ a(1) - a(2) + \cdots - a(N) \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n a(n) \leq a(1) - a(2) + \cdots - a(N) + a(N+1)$$
for any $N$. This is commonly proved while proving the alternating series test for convergence.

In practice, it is so much easier to understand the convergence of alternating series that sometimes is is better to figure out how to understand how to decompose an object into alternating series.

Comment: Note that the monotonicity is essential here, merely alternating in signs and eventually converging to zero is not enough, even though our intuition might think it should be ("the next term has the opposite sign and surely the next partial sum is closer to the infinite sum than this one is")

Comment: I see. That's a very nice answer, but I'm not sure it's powerful enough to give a simple proof of even $\cos(x) \geq 1-x^2$, or am I missing something? It seems that in order to apply it directly, we would need $x^/24, x^6/720, \ldots$ to be a non-increasing sequence, which is false for large $x$.  --- --- We can use your technique to show that the identity holds for small $x$ and handle large $x$ separately. I think this is probably better than the convexity approach, but not dramatically so.

Comment: I guess this technique also has some trouble handling series with rather complicated sign patterns such as the $\cos(x) \cos(x^2)$ example, whose series has a rather complex sign pattern. But, again, maybe I'm missing something, since I've used convexity to prove such statements quite a bit but haven't played much with this approach.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz $\cos(x) \geq 1-x^2/2$ for large $x$ can't be deduced solely by inspecting the first few terms of the Maclaurin series. After all, $1-x^2/2+x^4/24-x^6/120$ does not have this property (nor do any of the other truncations of the series with an even number of terms). Instead the breaking point of the inequality is pushed further and further away from zero as you take larger even numbers of terms.

Comment: @Ian, I'm not sure what it means "to deduce something from the Maclaurin series." I'm happy to use properties of the cosine, such as the fact that it is bounded or that its second derivative is its negative. (I guess something like this is necessary in some sense.) I think we've discussed two proofs of this inequality that are pretty simple. I'd just like a proof that generalizes to inequalities like $(*)$ or $(**)$ without too much hassle, since they come up quite a bit. (Maybe simple proofs don't exist, but that would be disappointing for such natural questions.)

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz What I mean is, if the proof is going to have something to do with series, it should hold for some (perhaps large) finite truncation of the series. But in the case of something like $\cos(x) \geq 1-x^2/2$ for all real $x$ it simply does not: you can only run this argument up to $(-\sqrt{12},\sqrt{12})$ (where $x^2/2<x^4/24$ holds) and then it breaks down. If you know additionally that $\cos$ has period $2\pi$ and $\pi<\sqrt{12}$ then you can use this to complete the proof, but that periodicity is highly nontrivial to deduce from the series.

Comment: @Ian It's probably bad form to continue this back-and-forth further. I'm not specifically asking for something that does not look at the entire series. E.g., certainly any reasonable technique should be powerful enough to prove $e^{-x} \geq 1-x$ for all $x$, which is not true for any odd partial sum.